# Attach variables

Tags: embedded, arduino

I want to take two variables (in and in2) and put them together, for example:

```
in = 1;
in2 = 3;

pin = in.in2; // I want this to set pin to 13
```

The arduino IDE tells me that in is not a class, so what syntax would I use to accomplish this?

EDIT: I figured out a different way to do it, you can just take `in`. multiply it by 10 and then set `pin` to the sum of `in` plus `in2`

Comment: Not a great solution if in2 > 9

Answer (score 1):

If your two variables are definitely integers then

```
pin = (in*10)+in2;
```

would work.

If not, read them into strings (maybe with in.toString(), language dependent) and just do

```
pin = int.parse(in.toString()+in2.toString());
```

(Although, again dependent on language, you may have to do something other than int.parse [in C# you should use int.TryParse() for example])

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I wrote it in **C** but you get the gist.  turn the two items into strings then concatenate and parse it as an integer.

```
pin = int.Parse((string)in + (string)in2);
```